# C#: Mapping a Data Type

Tags: c#, linq, data-structures

I've got to write a horrible interface to import data into a new database from hundreds of data files from our old application that has everything hard coded (the data displayed resemble Excel spreadsheets, and it allows us to export the data to Comma Delimited Values).

I can read it all in, with the header names.

From that, I can generate a name for the column to be used in a Sql CE Database.

The data currently consists of `float`, `int`, `DateTime`, `bit`, `char` and `string`.

I've come up with a *way* to do this (untested on all of our data), but any help from someone that knows how to code this better would be greatly appreciated.

The code below is not necessary to read through unless someone just doesn't understand what I'm asking.

```
public enum MyParameterType { NA, Float, Bool, Char, Date, Int, String }

class MyParameter {

public MyParameter(string name, string value) {
  if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(name) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) {
    throw new NotSupportedException("NULL values are not allowed.");
  }
  Name = name.Trim();
  Value = value.Trim();
  Type = MyParameterType.NA;
  if (-1 < Value.IndexOf('.')) { // try float
    float f;
    if (float.TryParse(Value, out f)) {
      string s = f.ToString();
      if (s == Value) {
        Parameter = new SqlCeParameter(AtName, SqlDbType.Float) { Value = f };
        Type = MyParameterType.Float;
      }
    }
  }
  if (Type == MyParameterType.NA) {
    bool b;
    if (bool.TryParse(Value, out b)) {
      Parameter = new SqlCeParameter(AtName, SqlDbType.Bit) { Value = b };
      Type = MyParameterType.Bool;
    }
  }
  if (Type == MyParameterType.NA) {
    if (Value.Length == 1) {
      char c = Value[0];
      Parameter = new SqlCeParameter(AtName, SqlDbType.Char) { Value = c };
      Type = MyParameterType.Char;
    }
  }
  if (Type == MyParameterType.NA) {
    DateTime date;
    if (DateTime.TryParse(Value, out date)) {
      Parameter = new SqlCeParameter(AtName, SqlDbType.DateTime) { Value = date };
      Type = MyParameterType.Date;
    }
  }
  if (Type == MyParameterType.NA) {
    if (50 < Value.Length) {
      Value = Value.Substring(0, 49);
    }
    Parameter = new SqlCeParameter(AtName, SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50) { Value = this.Value };
    Type = MyParameterType.String;
  }
}

public string AtName { get { return "@" + Name; } }

public string Name { get; set; }

public MyParameterType Type { get; set; }

public SqlCeParameter Parameter { get; set; }

public string Value { get; set; }

}
```

My biggest concern is that I don't want to mistakenly interpret one of the inputs (like a boolean value to be a char).

I am also looking for a way to compare new instances of `MyParameter` (i.e. if it is less than one type, try another type).

Bonus points for seeing some cool new expressions to generate this!

Comment: [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is perhaps a more suitable place for this question.

Comment: @Steven: maybe he could cross-post it, but I think this is interesting enough to stay on SO for the time being.

Comment: You can only _assume_ the type based on the rows you've currently read from a data file - so I'd suggest that you should read all the rows in a file and adjust your 'best guess' as you go.  Given your list of types, a column that looks to contain an integer may be 'downgraded' to a float or char or string - the more rows you read, the further down this slope you may go.

Comment: Another option is to take a sample of the rows and use those to determine the types (i.e. quorum vote).

Comment: @jp2code - P.S. I hope you do a better job of guessing the types than the SSIS Flat File source.  Anyone know if they've upped the max. rows to check when determining types in 2008 R2?  :)

Comment: Actually, I was thinking of starting with a `List<MyParameter>` object, walk through every row of the data using a row's own `List<MyParameter>`, then comparing the results to determine the best type (hence my desire to come up with a compare feature, too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given some abstract `CsvReader`:

```
using (var reader = new CsvReader(file))
{
    TableGuess table = new TableGuess { Name = file };

    // given: IEnumerable<string> CsvReader.Header { get; }
    table.AddColumns(reader.Header);

    string[] parts;
    while (null != (parts = reader.ReadLine()))
    {
        table.AddRow(parts);
    }
}
```

Your `ColumnGuess`:

```
class ColumnGuess
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Type Type { get; set; }
    public int Samples { get; private set; }

    public void ImproveType(string value)
    {
        if (this.Samples > 10) return;
        this.Samples++;

        float f; bool b; DateTime d; int i;
        if (Single.TryParse(value, out f))
        {
            this.Type = typeof(float);
        }
        else if (Boolean.TryParse(value, out b))
        {
            this.Type = typeof(bool);
        }
        else if (DateTime.TryParse(value, out d))
        {
            this.Type = typeof(DateTime);
        }
        else if (value.Length == 1 && this.Type == null && !Char.IsDigit(value[0]))
        {
            this.Type = typeof(char);
        }
        else if (this.Type != typeof(float) && Int32.TryParse(value, out i))
        {
            this.Type = typeof(int);
        }
    }
}
```

`TableGuess` would contain the guessed columns and the rows:

```
class TableGuess
{
    private List<string[]> rows = new List<string[]>();
    private List<ColumnGuess> columns;

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public void AddColumns(IEnumerable<string> columns)
    {
        this.columns = columns.Select(cc => new ColumnGuess { Name = cc })
                              .ToList();
    }

    public void AddRow(string[] parts)
    {
        for (int ii = 0; ii < parts.Length; ++ii)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(parts[ii])) continue;
            columns[ii].ImproveType(parts[ii]);
        }

        this.rows.Add(parts);
    }
}
```

You could add to `TableGuess` an `AsDataTable()` method:

```
public DataTable AsDataTable()
{
    var dataTable = new dataTable(this.Name);
    foreach (var column in this.columns)
    {
        dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(
            column.Name,
            column.Type ?? typeof(string)));
    }

    foreach (var row in this.rows)
    {
        object[] values = new object[dataTable.Columns.Count];
        for (int cc = 0; cc < row.Length; ++cc)
        {
            values[cc] = Convert.ChangeType(row[cc],
                dataTable.Columns[cc].DataType);
        }

        dataTable.LoadRow(values, false);
    }

    return dataTable;
}
```

You could use an `SqlCeDataAdapter` to move the data in the `DataTable` (after adding the table itself to the database).

Comment: I have it check the first 10 records it is given as a "speed up". But it may be worth letting it check all records for column types. Also, in the `AsDataTable` method you could do your error checking near the `Convert.ChangeType` and output/reject bad rows.

Comment: In **AsDataTable**, what are the two "??" in `column.Type ?? typeof(string)));`? Is that the new syntax for allowing defaults?

Comment: @jp2code: The `??` is the `null` coallescing operator. Basically: return the item on the left-hand-side if it is not null, otherwise return the right-hand-side. In this case it will return `typeof(string)` when the column's Type is null.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is not in that code, it seems like a way to know because you are always receiving the params as string, i think you can try it better but in the data extraction step,

Maybe with the header columns you can "parse them" to a type..

and try

```
Convert.ChangeType(yourValue, typeof(string, double,etc))
```

Comment: I have not tested this, but would the `ChangeType` method convert a value? That is, if `input="1.05"` and I tried `int num = (int)Convert.ChangeType(input, typeof(int));` ...would it throw an exception, set `num = 1`, or ...?

Comment: Yes, it should convert it, but with a valid cast like Convert.ChangeType('01/01/20100', typeof(DateTime)) or Convert.ChangeType('100.25', typeof(double)) but just with a  valid cast, the example that u ave it wont work because a double or float number cannot be converted to a int, it will throw you an exception

Answer (score 1):

How about this pseudo code - I reckon this should be fast enough for you.  This is very pseudo - so "string", "char" etc. are just placeholders for an enum value or whatever else you fancy.

```
For first data row in data file
  For each column in row
    TypeOfCol(column) = <best first guess>
  Next
Next

For each data row in data file
  For each column in row
    If TypeOfCol(column) = "string"
      Continue For
    If TypeOfCol(column) = "char"
      If columnValue has more than one character
        TypeOfCol(column) = "string"
        Continue For
    If TypeOfCol(column) = "bit"
      If columnValue isn't 1 or 0
        TypeOfCol(column) = "int" // Might not be an int - next If will pick up on that...
    If TypeOfCol(column) = "int"
      If columnValue isn't integer
        TypeOfCol(column) = "float"
    If TypeOfCol(column) = "float"
      If columnValue isn't a float
        TypeOfCol(column) = If(columnValue has more than one character then "string" else "char")
    If TypeOfCol(column) = "datetime"
      If columnValue isn't a date/time
        TypeOfCol(column) = "string"
  Next
Next
```

Comment: +1; however, reading in a string of text, shouldn't the `"string"` test be the dead last default?

Comment: I put the string check first as if you already know the column is a string then it won't change from this - so not worth checking other types.  `TypeOfCol` is intended to be e.g. a Dictionary that stores the current presumed type for the given column.